# What is $(-1)^\infty$?

Tags: limits, infinity

The result is probably that it is undefined but we can say that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \in \{-1, 1\}$. Right? Could we continue the calculation by considering separate cases with $1$ and $-1$ ? This is studied in the case of sequences therefor $n$ is always an integer.

Comment: Infinity is not a number and cannot be used in an algebraic expression. Therefore $(-1)^\infty$ is meaningless until explicitly defined.

Comment: See [Question 260876: What is infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260876/what-exactly-is-infinity).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $1^{\infty}$ considered to be an indeterminate form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form)

Comment: Instead consider $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Jonathcraft: *"... we can say that $(-1)^\infty\in\{-1,1\}$. Right?"* ... You're assuming "$\infty$" is not merely a *number*, but an *integer*. Stepping back from that, you might want to assert instead that $\left|(-1)^\infty\right|=1$. (See @ Mourad's comment.)

Comment: Expand it to $(-1)^x=\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: Re your last line: How can you simultaneously replace a single symbol by two different values?

Comment: @Blue I assume "$\infty$" to be an integer because I want to study this in the context of sequences.

Comment: @Jonathcraft: You should include all such context in the body of the question. (Comments are easily overlooked.)

Comment: I edited my question, I was a bit lazy on the notation :)

Comment: @Mourad I edited my question because $x$ is always an integer

Comment: The limit of the sequence $1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots$ is undefined, so it isn't proper to make any statement that treats "$\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n$" as a number. However, in certain contexts, it *is* proper to state that $+1$ and $-1$ are each ["limit points"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of the sequence. (The Wikipedia entry gives the example $(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$, which has no limit, but two *limit points* (namely, $+1$ and $-1$).) It's a subtle, but significant, distinction.

Comment: The limit itself already has a definition, and using that definition, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n$ doesn't exist.  That said, there is the concept of "the set of sub sequential limits" which is a useful generalization of the limit studied in its own right, and seems to be exactly what you are talking about.