# What is the cardinality of the set of infinite cardinalities?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I am currently aware of only two infinite cardinalities:

- $\aleph_0 = |\Bbb N|$
- $\aleph_1 = |\Bbb R|$

Questions:

1. Is there an infinite number of infinite cardinalities?
2. If yes, is this set of cardinalities countable or uncountable?

I know that $\aleph_0<\aleph_1$ and I would tend to guess that the set of infinite cardinalities is countable at most (or possibly even finite), since there is no known element $K$ such that $\aleph_0<K<\aleph_1$.

BTW, are there any other acceptable operations (such as $+,-,\times,/$) between elements in this set?

Thanks

Comment: $|\mathbb{R}|= \aleph_1$ is an undecidable assertion, and by definition there is *no* $\kappa$ such that $\aleph_0<\kappa<\aleph_1$

Comment: 1. Yes, by Cantor's theorem.   
 2. No. Class of all cardinals is not even a set!

Comment: 1. Because $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is always larger than $X$, you can easily get a countable number of cardinalities just by defining $X_0=\mathbb{N}$ and $X_i=\mathcal{P}(X_{i-1}$.

Comment: @Julien Godawatta : Thanks. By definition? I thought that this was an unproved hypothesis...

Comment: @tetori: Thanks. Why is it not a set?

Comment: @barakmanos Because the [Cantor's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_paradox), this class is not a set.

Comment: @barakmanos $\aleph_1$ is the successor cardinal of $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Julien Godawatta: Thanks. I meant "no $K$ such that $|N| < K < |R|$".

Comment: Next time please try to search the site first. Some threads answering this question are: [This thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11040/622) and [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/283581/622) and [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/8013/622) and [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1/622) and [that thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/383811/622). (Note that one of these is in fact the first question posted on the site.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, kudo's for being interested in the cardinal numbers. However, there's a few errors in the question, so lets just try to set the record straight.

The (currently standard) collection of set-theoretic principles is called [ZFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). So rather than asking "what is *true* of the cardinal numbers?" (vague question), let us ask "what can ZFC *prove* about the cardinal numbers?" (precise question).

ZFC proves the following sentences.

1. $\beth_0 = |\mathbb{N}|$
2. $\beth_1 = |\mathbb{R}|$ (but we cannot prove $\aleph_1 = |\mathbb{R}|$).
3. $\beth_0 < \beth_1$.
4. There exist infinitely-many infinite cardinal numbers.
5. There does **not** exist a set of all cardinal numbers.

See also, [beth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number), [aleph numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number).

*To see why there ought to exist infinitely-many infinite cardinal numbers:*

**Step 1.** Recall [Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem): $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$ for all sets $X$.

**Step 2.** Consider the following sequence. $$|\mathbb{N}|, |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|, |\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))|,...$$

(Of course, this is just the initial portion of the beth sequence: $\beth_0, \beth_1,\beth_2,\ldots$)

I might have a go answering some of your other questions a bit later.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. So from #5 I understand that there is no means by which we can count the number of infinite cardinalities, because we cannot define a set for them. Is that correct?

Comment: @barakmanos Ironically, even though the total collection is larger than any set, we can *count* them, in the generalized sense of ordinal "counting", which includes these magical "limit steps" which formalize the "$\dots$" in $$\aleph_0,\aleph_1,\aleph_2,\dots,\aleph_\omega, \aleph_{\omega+1},\dots,\aleph_{\omega\cdot2},\dots,\aleph_{\omega^2},\dots, \aleph_{\omega^\omega},\dots.$$ See the wiki article on [Ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) for details.

Comment: Commentary on the sets $|\Bbb N|,|{\cal P}\Bbb N|,|{\cal P}^2\Bbb N|,\dots$: The set $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}{\cal P}^n\Bbb N$ is a set (being a countable union of sets), and is clearly larger than any set in the union. Thus it cannot be smaller than $\beth_n$ for any $n\in\omega$. In fact, this set has cardinality $\beth_\omega$.

Comment: @barakmanos, kind of. Ill edit with clarification when I can find the time.

Comment: Can ZFC actually prove that that those iterated power sets all exist and are all distinct?

Comment: @JackM: Yes, in that the existence is an axiom, and the distinctness is (as mentioned in the answer) a theorem of Cantor.

Comment: Or we can talk about NF, in which the infinite cardinals are a set, Cantor's theorem fails, and it's an open question whether there are models with only finitely many infinite cardinals :D

Answer (score 6):

The "set" of cardinalities is not a set. It is a class. Every set is a class, but some classes are sets and some aren't. There are things that you can make with a set and not with a class, and one of these things is defining its cardinality. But a class that is not a set always has infinitely many elements.

So:

1. There is no "set of cardinalities". Thus, there is no cardinality of the set of cardinalities. I'm not sure, but this sounds like the typical thing that drives to paradox; perhaps the cardinality of the sets of cardinalities would be bigger than any other cardinality (that would be the reason that it doesn't exist).
2. There are infinitely many cardinalities. A simple proof has been written by JiK in his/her comment.

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28set_theory%29) for some details.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of the term `class`. Thanks.

Comment: _proper_ class.

Comment: Personally, I've come to believe that talk of "classes" just confuses things. Lets talk about models and theories instead. ZFC (a theory) proves there does not exist a set of all cardinal numbers. By the completeness theorem for first order logic, this is equivalent to the statement that the cardinal numbers of a universe cannot be internalized to that universe. More precisely, the statement is that "if $(M,\in')$ is a model of ZFC and $K \subseteq M$ is the set of $M$-cardinal numbers, then there is no $k \in M$ such that $K = \{m \in M \mid m \in' k\}.$"

Answer (score 1):

Q1.yes.there is not only an infinite number of infinite cardinalities,but the collection of infinite cardinals is a proper class,that is too big to be a set,bigger than all cardinals.
Q2.it is surely uncountable,and also bigger than all uncountable cardinals.
 aleph-1=cardinality of R is true if and only if CH is true,otherwise R can have cardinality aleph-2,aleph10,aleph-1232337312,or other alephs.cardinals have opertion + and *,a+b=a*b=max{a,b} for all infinite cardinals.- and / can not be defined.
you can have unimaginable big alephs,such as aleph-aleph-aleph-.......,aleph-0 times,that is the smallest cardinal such that aleph-a=a.BUT it is consisitent with ZFC,it is still smaller than the cardinality of R,2^aleph-null!!!aleph-x just means the xth infinite cardinal.