# How big is infinity?

Tags: infinity, philosophy

This might be more philosophy than math, but it’s been bothering me for a while.

> **Question:** If there’s an infinite amount of real numbers between $ 0 $ and $ 1 $, shouldn’t there be twice the amount of real numbers between $ 0 $ and $ 2 $? Wouldn’t that be $ 2 \times \infty $? What about the amount of real numbers between $ 0 $ and $ \infty $? Wouldn’t that be $ \infty \times \infty $?

I guess the whole concept of infinity just kind of evades me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question is not about mathematics.

Comment: There are several different not necessarily compatible measures of size. In the sense of cardinality, the set $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ have the same (infinite) cardinality. In the sense of measure, one has measure $1$ and the other has measure $2$.  With shapes, there are several   measures of size (surface area, volume). They are useful in different contexts (painting, carrying).

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383811/how-big-is-the-size-of-all-infinities?rq=1) and [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283581/how-many-different-sizes-of-infinity-are-there?rq=1) and [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664862/how-do-we-assume-there-is-infinity?rq=1)

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, define mathematics then.

Comment: "Infinity is pretty huge" ...

Comment: I don't entirely agree that this is not mathematics.  See what I wrote below.

Comment: "Infinity, is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to infinity, listen..."

Comment: You might find this short talk about [Cantor's diagonalization argument](http://ed.ted.com/lessons/how-big-is-infinity) interesting.

Comment: I always wanted to answer this question with, simply, "bigger than that."

Comment: Careful about treating infinity as an object.  $3x = 2x + 1 \rightarrow x=1$ doesn't hold if you treat infinity as a possible value for $x$.  In general, infinity should be thought of as a property, "infinite", and I recommend interpreting it as "not among the finite numbers", which doesn't necessarily mean larger.

Comment: There is a whole book on this topic.   "Infinity and the Mind: The Science and Philosophy of the Infinite" by Rudy Rucker. It explains all the different types of infinities in mathematics. Quite an intimidating read for the non-mathematicians, though.

Comment: You might also want to view Vi Hart's [How many kinds of infinity are there?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23I5GS4JiDg).

Comment: I would also recommend "The Quest for Infinity" by Brian Clegg.  Highly readable, even for the non-mathematician.

Comment: Well, obviously 42

Comment: Think about something. It`s bigger that that.
Repeat.

Comment: How is this question getting more than 1 upvote/h ?

Comment: @metacompactness: It's featured as a "Hot Network Question" in the sidebar and probably attacks a lot of non-mathematicians from other sites. After what I've seen on other questions I wish these featured questions would be locked from upvotes at the time of their "promotion".

Comment: These questions are becoming more frequent from new users and they are getting irrational upvoting. Attention moderators.

Comment: (Ignoring that infinity is not really a number but a cardinality...) Sure, there are twice as many real numbers between 0 and 2 as between 0 and 1. It's just that twice infinity is... infinity.

Comment: I want to point you to this vihart video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23I5GS4JiDg

Comment: For every unique number x you find in [0,2] you can find a unique number x/2 in [0,1] but also the other way around for every unique number x in [0,1] you can find a unique number x*2 in [0,2]. Does this mean there are exactly the same amount of numbers in [0,1] as in [0,2]? –  Pieter B 46 secs ago

Comment: It's infinitely big.

Comment: Because the phrase "number of numbers", when you get to the reals, is vague and can mean *many* different things, I think that the Lebesgue measure should be mentioned. It encapsulates in what sense there can be "more" in one real set than another, even if they're equal in cardinality.

Comment: Your second sentence is very troubling. What do you think is special about the interval $[0,1]$? You could have chosen $[0,0.5]$, and you would then have concluded $[0,2]$ has $4\cdot\infty$.

Comment: asking how big is infinity has no sense since it is has no size which can be actually counted.It is not possible to talk about it as in the sense of something which can be counted..thereforce infinty

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPA3bwVVzGI <-- this video

Comment: The BBC In Our Time has a talk on infinity at http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0054927 (may not be available outside the UK)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I [answered a similar question on May 13th](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793693/is-infinity-a-real-or-complex-quantity/793725#793725):

> There are many different things that could be called "the infinite" in mathematics.  **None** of them is a real number or a complex number, but some are used in discussing functions or real or complex numbers.
>
> - There are things called $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.  Those appear in such expressions as
>     $$
>     \lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{1+2^x} = 1 \text{ and }\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{1+2^x}=0.
>     $$
> - There is also an $\infty$ that is approached as $x$ goes in either direction along the line.  That occurs in
>     $$
>     \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{1-x} = -1\text{ and }\lim_{x\to1} \frac{x}{1-x}=\infty.
>     $$
>     The second limit above could be said to approach $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from one direction and $-\infty$ if from the other direction, but if one has just one $\infty$ at both ends of the line, then one makes the rational function a continuous function at the point where it has a vertical asymptote.  This may be regarded as the same $\infty$ that appears in the theory of complex variables.
> - There are "points at infinity" in projective geometry.  This is similar to the "infinity" in the bullet point immediately preceding this one.  Two parallel lines meet at infinity, and it's the same point at infinity regardless of which of the two directions you take along the lines.  But two non-parallel lines pass through *different* points at infinity rather than the same point at infinity.  Thus any two lines in the projective plane intersect exactly once.
> - There are cardinalities of infinite sets such as $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ (which is countably infinite) or $\mathbb R$ (which is uncountably infinite).  When it is said that Euclid proved there are infinitely many prime numbers, this sort of "infinity" is referred to.
> - One regards an integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ as a sum of infinitely many infinitely small quantities, and a derivative $dy/dx$ as a quotient of two infinitely small quantities.  This is a different idea from all of the above.
> - Consider the step function $x\mapsto\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x<0, \\  1 & \text{if } x\ge 0. \end{cases}$  One can say that its rate of change is infinite at $x=0$.  This "infinity" admits multiplication by real numbers, so that for example, the rate of change at $0$ of the function that is $3.2$ times this function, is just $3.2$ times the "infinity" that is the rate of change of the original step function at $0$.  This is made precise is the very useful theory of Dirac's delta function.
> - There is the "infinite" of Robinson's nonstandard analysis.  In that theory, we learn that if $n$ is an infinite positive integer, then evern "internal" one-to-one function that maps $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n-3\}$ into $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ omits exactly three elements of the latter set from its image.  Nothing like that holds for cardinalities of infinite sets discussed above.
> - I'm sure there are other examples that I'm missing here.

Comment: Great answer. Arguably Euclid's proof of the infinitude of the primes doesn't need anything to do with cardinalities or collections of integers. Saying that there are infinitely many primes is shorthand for saying that no matter what bound you pick there's always a bigger prime.

Comment: Might want to mention the hyperreals and surreals as well.  (You allude to them with "Robinson's nonstandard analysis", but describing $\omega$ such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \sum_0^k 1 < \omega$ might be clearer.)

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning infinite ordinals. Especially because that is one case where multiplying $\infty$ ($\omega$) by $2$ actually makes sense.

Comment: @Zack : By "hyperreals" do you mean something other than Robinson's theory that I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @MichaelHardy At the time I wrote that I had forgotten that Robinson's theory and the hyperreals were the same thing.  As I tried to explain in my edited comment, I think a gentler introduction to Robinson's theory talks about $\mathbb{R}^\star \supset \mathbb{R}$ and the extended (infinite and infinitesmal) elements of $\mathbb{R}^\star$.  Conway's surreals, however, are their own thing AFAIK.

Comment: @MichaelHardy One question; about the parallel lines. Imagine two parallel lines parallel to X axis. Where they intersect - on the left or on the right? Or both, but still in single point? (The latter looks somehow "logical", but also it means that there is point on the place which can be reached in both directions...)

Comment: They meet at a single point at infinity that is approached by moving in either direction along the line.

Answer (score 42):

User wrote:

> If there is an infinite amount of numbers between $ 0 $ and $ 1 $, shouldn’t there be twice that amount between $ 0 $ and $ 2 $?

No. Every real number in the interval $[0,1]$ can be mapped one-to-one to every real number in $[0,2]$ using the function $f(x)=2x$. So, there are no more numbers in $[0,2]$ than there are in $[0,1]$.

Comment: +1 - Why can't we all be more succinct?

Comment: -1: I'm sorry, but this does not explain it to me. It makes sense, **but** if there are infinite natural numbers, and infinite real numbers between each natural number, how can the number of natural numbers and the number of real numbers be the same infinity, and not different orders of magnitude?

Comment: @ANeves No, you're right. There are *more* real numbers than there are natural numbers. What this answer is claiming is that there are just as many real numbers in $[0,1]$ as there are in $[0,2]$.

Comment: @ANeves to piggyback on what David was saying, though both the natural numbers and the real numbers are infinite, they are not equivalent in size. One thing many laypeople do not understand or realize is that infinity is not a number, it's not equal to any number, and that two infinities can be different (or the same) in size from one another.

Comment: (Btw, I can't really downvote with less than 150rep.) Ah, I see, thanks! Then I think this answer should actually be "No. **Infinity is not a number**, and (...)". The question being a layperson's, the answer should be to a layperson's.

Comment: (Set A being contained in set B, set B having items that are not in set A, and A having `just as many real numbers` as B... that still *does not work* in my head. But I can accept it - intuition can't always be right.)

Comment: @ANeves What does it mean that there are as many elements in $A$ as in $B$? Just that there exists a bijection $f:A\to B$, i.e. the elements of one set can be matched up 1-to-1 to all elements in the other set.

Comment: "What does it mean that there are as many elements in A as in B? Just that there exists a bijection..." You speak of that "meaning" as it were some metaphysical truth, when it's just a mathematical definition - which makes sense, up to a point and in some definite context. Other has the right to claim "to speak of (or compare) the 'amount of elements' of infinite sets make no sense - end of history" hey, some even say "there are no such 'things' as infinite sets, they are only a sort of limit concept"

Comment: @leonbloy Yeah, it takes all kinds.

Answer (score 22):

I have a rule of thumb: anything that says "infinity" (as opposed to $\aleph_0$, $\beth_2$, $\varepsilon_0$, $+\infty$, (projective) point at infinity, infinite, $\omega$, etc.) is probably not mathematics. It's not that mathematicians are afraid of the infinite -- hardly! -- but that it's an imprecise collection of heterogeneous concepts. Math is more precise than that.

In this case you're talking about the number of elements in a set (of real numbers), and so the particular concept you're talking about is called cardinality. The set [0, 1] has the same cardinality or 'size' as [0, 2]: precisely $2^{\aleph_0}=\beth_1.$

If you look at the fractions in [0, 1] and [0, 2] you'd find that, again, they have the same cardinality as each other, but a different cardinality from the above. This time they're 'just' $\aleph_0=\beth_0.$

If you drop all the way down to the integers the cardinality of the integers in [0, 1] is 2 while thee cardinality of the integers in [0, 2] is 3 and so these are no longer the same.

Comment: The first statement is wrong. Mathematicians work with the infinite just fine, and quite precisely. The problem is that when a *layperson* uses the word "infinity", they often  do so in an imprecise way that only loosely corresponds to a mathematical idea if at all. (and often resist the notion that there can even be mathematical ideas about the infinite)

Comment: @Hurkyl To be fair, that could be argued to be a distinction between the infinite and the _word_ 'infinity', which - even in e.g. set theory - very seldom actually crops up (in lieu of more precise terms, of course!).

Comment: @Hurkyl: Say what you will, this is my rule of thumb. If I see "$+\infty$" there's no problem, if I see "$\aleph_0$" there's no problem, but if I see "infinity" it's almost never mathematical. In fact this is one of my most useful heuristics, better than the "real math papers use TeX" heuristic.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: You beat me to it! Yes, that's precisely what I'm saying.

Comment: @Steven: That's because the noun infinity usually crops up in *geometry*: e.g. positive and negative infinity of the extended reals (the same infinity that appears in "the limit is infinity"), or the points at infinity of the projective plane.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ack, very good point that!  I was somewhat primed for set theory because of the question (loosely, treating infinity as a _size_ rather than a _place_) but you're absolutely right that that's a precise and canonical concept.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I have no problem with $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, nor with "points at infinity" or any other concrete notion, but the fluffy unqualified "infinity" is rarely used in math.

Comment: @Charles That is a far more cautious statement than your initial statement in this answer.

Comment: @Brilliand: The purpose of the statement was just to provide a reference frame for understanding the main claim of the paragraph: that when mathematicians talk about the infinite they have a particular kind in mind, and "infinity" itself is ambiguous. If the topic was distinguishing mathematics from philosophy I would have been much more nuanced -- but to do so here would take away from my main point. (On the other hand, if what you're saying is that you're interested in my heuristics here, I could say a good deal -- ask a CW question and ping me.)

Comment: what the heck is ℶ symbol?

Comment: @Templar: The letter beth (or bet), the second letter in the Hebrew alphabet. $\beth_0$ is the cardinality of the integers (the 'smallest infinity') and they are defined recursively as $\beth_{n+1}=2^{\beth_n}$ where the symbol denotes cardinal exponentiation: if $\mathfrak{a}$ is a set, $2^\mathfrak{a}$ is the set of maps from $\mathfrak{a}$ to $\{0,1\}.$ So $\beth_1$ is the cardinality of the real numbers, a much larger infinite cardinal.

Comment: I second @Hurkyl's sentiment. I believe the first statement, as written, is misleading. Mathematicians use the word "infinity" or "infinite" quite frequently, but from the given context they can glean the precise meaning intended.

Comment: @J.Loreaux: I intentionally excluded "infinite" -- this is very common in mathematics.

Answer (score 16):

Intuitively, you are treating the "quantity" called *infinity* just like an ordinary real number. This is the defect.

You have a definition of $\infty$ and prove whether it satisfies the properties of real numbers, if yes, then you may say that,

> If there is an infinite amount of numbers between $ 0 $ and $ 1 $, shouldn’t there be twice that amount between $ 0 $ and $ 2 $?

Note that you have assumed that the quantity $2$ $.$ $\infty$ is defined similarly as we define $x . y$ in $\mathbb {R}$.

Basically you may have assumed $\infty$ to be a very very big real number. This is the basic flaw, since $\infty$ is not a member of $\mathbb {R}$.

Answer (score 4):

The ideas of being "of  the  same size", here , referring to your question we are dealing with cardinality,  that we understand in the world of the finite, break down when we have infinite sets. There are formal definitions of what it means for two infinite sets to have the same size/cardinality or, informally,  having the same amount of terms. There is a whole precisely-defined arithmetic of infinite cardinalities, with precisely-stated meanings, e.g.: $X^Y$ is the cardinality of all the functions from a set of cardinality represented by $X$ to a set with cardinality represented by $Y$.

Specifically, two infinite sets $X,Y$ have the same size if there is a one-one , onto map between them, i.e., if there is a bijection between $X,Y$ (there are related results like the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem that tell you that if there is an injection between $X,Y$ and an injection between $Y,X$ then there is a bijection between the two).
  In our case, since we can find a bijection between the two intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$, by our definition, the two have the same size (cardinality).

To answer your question, $2 \infty$ is decided by whther we can find a bijection between a set of that same infinite cardinality and the disjoint union of the set with itself.

Like Andre Nicolas stated in the comments, you can consider different measures of size, such as length, or measure in general. So one can have sets of the same cardinality but with different measure.

Comment: What is the downvote about?

Answer (score 3):

Infinity can be as big as you want it to be. It can be in the interval between 0 and 1, or it can be in the interval between 0 and 2, or in the interval between $(-3)^7$ to $10^{10^{10^{34}}}$, etc. I take it you've heard the term "infinitesimally small."

*Try* to count how many rational numbers there are between 0 and 1. Better yet, try to count how many rational numbers there are between 0 and 1 which can be expressed with a denominator that is a power of 2. There is $\frac{1}{2}$. There is $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$. And $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{3}{8}$, $\frac{5}{8}$, $\frac{7}{8}$, ... you get the idea. Now try the same thing between 0 and 2. There's 1. There's $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$. And $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{4}$, $\frac{5}{4}$, and well, you run into the same problem.

In your mind, imagine a typical 12-inch ruler. But with this ruler, you can make the tickmarks as small as you want, whereas with a real ruler, you would get to a point at which you have to make the tickmarks so small you can't even see them.

The concept of infinity can easily lead to a lot of paradoxes, as well as statements that look nonsensical, like $\infty^2 = \infty^\infty = \infty$. I suggest you read http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/infinity_paradox.htm

Comment: Welcome to math.se! I didn't know you had an account here.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. Only very recently, after I suggested it to an OEIS contributor.

Comment: In what context is $\infty^{\infty} = \infty$ true?

Comment: Maybe only when a mathematician or a smart-aleck is asking. Assuming Tetyana Butler is right, I think that $\infty^\infty$ follows from her assertion that $\infty^2 = \infty$.

Comment: I can "accept" $\infty^2 = \infty$ since this for example is true if we replace $\infty$ by any infinite cardinal. But I cannot think of a context where we can both make sense of $\infty^{\infty}$ and have it equal $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not try to tackle understanding "infinity" head on. It's literally too much for human mind. So I'll try to give an "intuitively" understandable answer, thus avoiding "infinity" from now on:

All the numbers in [0, 2] can easily fit into [0, 1]! We can play a game to show this:
You provide a number from [0, 2] and I'll return a number from [0, 1]. For any different numbers, I'll lose, if I fail to provide different numbers. I can only win, if I convince you that I won't lose.

`You may start with 2.`
I'll go with 1.

`Maybe 1?`
0.5

`square root of 2!` (square root of 2) divided by 2.

`Zero, got ya.` Nope, zero, too.

`Any number.` Half that number.

See, what I'm getting at? There are as many numbers in [0, 1] as there are in [0, 2], because I can define a method to get one for every one you provide. I'll assume this is convincing enough and I won the game.

So to measure something that is too huge to measure, you just compare it, piece by piece, to something about the same size. Well, actually you don't compare, but tell how you would compare. If you can find a way to compare, piece by piece, it's not bigger.

The problem is to find a way to compare piece by piece. The only help I can give you in this, is the advice to avoid confusing yourself by **the-bad-word**. Instead ask yourself: "Where does the huge number of pieces come from?"

- [0, 2] looks **twice** as big as [0, 1]. But it's not, if you half it!
- [0, x] looks x times as big as [0, 1]. So as long as you can divide by x, everything is fine.
- We all know that dividing by zero isn't allowed. So we found something that's "smaller": [0, 0] has only one element, so it's clearly smaller.
- I disallowed myself from using **the-bad-word**. So I need to put it like this: If x keeps growing. What will happen to say 1/x?

At some point `1 divided by ever-growing-x` will be indistinguishable close to 0. And if you can't distinguish between 0 and `1/ever-growing-x` the piece to piece comparison fails. This makes [0, ever-growing-x] "bigger" than [0, 1] or [0, not-growing-x].

The next step would be to have a look at y-growing-way-faster-than-x. But I guess that'd overdo things.

Comment: Excellent layperson answer.

Comment: Your example is correct, but you should also note that with this function you need to get all of the elements in [0,1].  I can map {0,1,2,3...} to [0,1] by sticking a decimal point on the left of the number, but [0,1] is bigger.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas: You're right. But I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. So the comparison does only answer is A bigger than B with "yes" or "no". It does **not** answer "No, B is bigger than A.".
BTW: Yes, it is a layperson answer, because the OP indicated to be a layperson. So thank you, for the compliment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great anecdotal way to learn about different sizes of infinity.

[Wikipedia Article - Hilbert's Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel)

So there are different sizes of infinity.  Suppose you have two sets `A` and `B` and both of those sets are full of infinite things, that is, each of those two sets has infinite items.  Not to say that they are they same size, one of their infinities may be bigger than the other.

If for every single item in `A` I can map it to exactly one item in `B` and I have all items in `B` covered, then the two sets are the same size of infinity.

If in all 1-1 mapping from `A` to `B` in which all items in `A` are used there are always items in `B` leftover, then the size of `B` is a bigger infinity than that of `A`.

Comment: I didn't use the normal "for all" terminology, but I think I addressed your point.  In my defense, its been a while... :-D
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, except for the mapping __s__ typo.

Answer (score 0):

You need a little set theory to understand this concept well.

If a set s has infinite amount of elements then there exists a function f from S to a subset of S ( say T, note that T != S ).

Just that easy !

Now, Why does N (1, 2, ,3 , 4, ...) have infinite elements?

Consider f(x) = x + 1 it maps whole N to "N - { 1 }" therefore N so .

Why does R have infinite members!? Because we can find functions like f(x) = 1/x which map whole r between a subset of R ( here between 0 & 1 ).

That's all I known ... I hope it helps.
If you are interested in set theory I recommend "Lectures in logic & set theory vol2" ( hey I am not a mathematics expert if you ask a more experienced one you shall get better resources )

Answer (score -1):

Infinity is so large, it can contain multiple copies of itself, within itself.  It's not at all like any of the other numbers, so many of the "common sense" approaches to infinity don't make a lot of sense.

That answer that pointed you to Cantor's Diagonalization Argument...  yes, that's the way to go...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to treat $\infty$ more or less as a real number, look into hyperreal numbers. A hyperreal number is essentially a number defined by a sequence, which may or may not be limited. Therefore it is possible to say that the sequence $\{2,4,6,...\}$ is twice as large as the sequence $\{1,2,3,...\}$, even though both approach $\infty$. However, good luck applying hyperreals to the set of numbers between $0$ and $1$. That particular type of infinity is very difficult to define or measure, and almost completely useless.