# Are there any good books on infinity?

Tags: reference-request, infinity

I am looking for a book that discusses the concepts of infinity like the actual infinite and related concepts. Any suggestions?

Comment: I only read an excerpt, but it was recommended by someone I trust: [The Infinite](http://www.amazon.com/Infinite-Problems-Philosophy-A-W-Moore/dp/0415252857) by [A.W. Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._W._Moore_(philosopher)).

Answer (score 4):

For a nice introduction to the many different notions of infinity in mathematics see Rudy Rucker's book: [Infinity and the Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691001723). Unlike many other popularizations, this is written by someone who did a Ph.D. on the topic. Rucker goes to great lengths to make the presentation faithful to the mathematics but still accessible to an educated layperson. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5390/242) for an excerpt on Alephs.

Comment: Is there a more mathematical book you would suggest on the topic ?

Comment: @Sashas I'm not aware of one that covers all of the topics in Rucker's book.