# what does it mean ' infinity comes in different sizes'?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

What does mean when mathematicians say infinity comes in different sizes ?

Comment: It means what it means, that infinity comes in different sizes. What do you think it means?

Comment: Numberphile "broke a rule" and made a nice video about infinity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elvOZm0d4H0

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1 has a bunch of other similar and related questions. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/types-of-infinity is a good companion question, with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/5378 to complement that, too. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182171/are-all-infinities-equal and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/182171, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here we mean that two sets are the same size of infinite if there exists a one-to-one and onto transformation  from one set to the other.

For example:
There are an equal number of integers even integers by the transformation

$$
T : \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow   2\mathbb{Z}
$$

Defined by
$$
T(a) = 2a \ \ \ \text{ for all}\ \ \  a \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

This is equivalent to saying we can list the items one by one, try this with two finite sets to see how it works. We can also list all rational numbers one by one, give this a try. So there are the same number of rationals as integers.

Now we can't list all reals, meaning there are more reals than integers and rationals.