# Book/article/tutorial as an introduction to Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, infinity

I study CS, but on the first semester I have a lot of mathematics. Of course, there is an introduction to set theory and logic. Recently, we had lectures about cardinality, different kinds of infinity, countable sets etc. I know the basics, but I don't understand many ideas as I would like to understand them.

Well, I am looking for a book/article/tutorial/etc. which is a good explanation of cardinality, countable sets, idea of different kinds of infinity and cardinality of sets of different functions. Now, I only need sources, which cover the basics, but I don't mind if You post something on higher level (but *introduction stuff* has greater priority).

PS: I was looking for similar questions on this site, I've found for exaple [1] and [2], but it isn't what I'm actually looking for.

I woluld appreciate You help.

[1] [Cardinality of set of real continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477/cardinality-of-set-of-real-continuous-functions)

[2] [What Does it Really Mean to Have Different Kinds of Infinities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1/different-kinds-of-infinities)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind relatively high level reading (though it starts from the basics, you just need to be able to even read mathematical texts):

[Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic](https://books.google.com/books?id=wlqSgRJ42-EC)

The preface and first chapter is about introduction to cardinal arithmetic, you probably don't need it all, but there's a good introductory part there.

Answer (score 6):

I like Devlin's "Joy of Sets".

Answer (score 6):

This is at least the fifth time I have posted this on this site.  But it is free, so here it comes again:

I have some relatively brief notes on introductory set theory available on my webpage.  Please go to [this page](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/expositions2012.html) and scroll most of the way down to the bottom.  Or more directly go [this page](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/settheorypart1.pdf).

If you get to the end of these notes and are still curious, try replacing the "1" by a "2", and so forth.  However the first set of notes is intended to be particularly easy going, to be used by undergraduates with absolutely no prior background in set theory.

Comment: Hey, your "expositions" link here seems broken. Also, thanks a bunch, I'm going to try these notes out on an intermediate analysis class I'm currently teaching. Looks like fun.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for something slightly different, but Cantor's "Contributions to the Founding of the Theory of Transfinite Numbers" is a delight to read.

Comment: I believe, that it's "delight to read", but (as You already wrote) I'm looking for something different ;)

Answer (score 2):

Goldrei's Classic Set Theory is extremely well written and easy to read, and covers cardinalities

Answer (score 2):

There is Set Theory, by K. Kuratowski and A. Mostowski.
It's dry as dirt and yet for some reason I loved reading that book.

If it's available in your library, I'd take it home and see if it works out.