# Is there some more fundamental math theory than logic?

Tags: logic, foundations

As I know logic is mathematical theory which studies mathematical theories themselves, but is there some mathematical theory which is more fundamental ? By more fundamental I mean that this theory maybe studies logic itself or studies structures as logic. My question can also be interpreted as:"Is there some theory which is "lower" in chain of deducing whole mathematics ?".

Comment: no idea, i would imagine it would be something axiomatic, then again the most basic arguement is the basal axioms so....yeah logic from there

Comment: @Vaas So there is no such theory ?

Comment: Mathematics as a whole is absorbent in an odd sense. In particular, any "theory" which might have the ability to properly formalize mathematics is already formalizable within mathematics (I'm being intentionally vauge.)

Comment: My answer to [How do I convince someone that $1+1=2$ may not necessarily be true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/how-do-i-convince-someone-that-11-2-may-not-necessarily-be-true/246724#246724) might be of interest.

Comment: @NotMike So is mathematical logic this theory ?

Comment: well lets consider it logically yes? first things first. do you agree to the 3 basal axioms? ie...the universe exists, and we all occupy the same universe.

Events happen in the universe which are observable.

from these observations we can learn something

(been a while but i think these were the basal axioms)

Comment: You might be interested to study philosophy (of mathematics, logic and/or language). Also this might interest you: https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/whatrests.pdf