# Quantum physics and principle of non-contradiction

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, quantum-mechanics

We all know that mathematics is based on axioms in the science of logic. These axioms we proceed through to prove the validity or falsehood of any statement. One of the most important of these axioms is the principle of non-contradiction, which is to assume that something false is true , then we reach a contradiction, so we conclude that it is wrong. Many of those who introduce popular science and some physicists say that quantum physics allow the contradiction to occur, for example in the so-called Schrödinger's cat,As they say the cat is alive and dead together at the same time which oppose the law of non-contradiction. And alot of similar examples. Also when they talk about a superposition Which is the sum of two vectors in a Hilbert space they also say the electron spin up and spin down at the same time and in the same sense as an interpretation for quantum superposition , so how true are these allegations? and Can any experiment contradict the laws of mathematical logic?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are attempts to manage contradictions; see e.g. [Paraconsistent Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/), [Dialetheism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/), [Quantum Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ok i will do it

Comment: To be fair, [QL](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/#InteQuanLogi) does not reject the NC principle. Maybe we have to consider [Quantum Computing](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantcomp/): if a quantum computer perform computations, we can assume that we have no contradictions...

Comment: *quantum physics allow the contradiction to occur* -- The use of "paradox" in reference to Schrödinger's cat or quantum superposition is not a paradox in quantum physics itself, but rather a paradox between quantum physics and classical (non-quantum) physics, so (at least) one of these must be incorrect, and since quantum physics reduces to classical physics when Planck's constant approaches zero, classical physics is more suspect, although of course classical physics is still "correct in non-quantum domains" like my walking from one room to another room doesn't affect the Moon's orbit.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I tried the tags you gave me, but it didn't accept, I don't know why

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Excuse me, just to clarify. Do you mean that the contradiction occurs if we try to explain quantum physics by the laws of classical physics, and not that the contradiction is in quantum mechanics itself?

Comment: There is no contradiction. The system is either in the state $| \text{cat alive}\rangle$, the state $| \text{cat dead}\rangle$ or a superposed state $\alpha | \text{cat alive}\rangle + \beta | \text{cat dead}\rangle$. But it's not in those states at the same time. The problem with Schrödinger's cat is that we do not observe the superposed states. It's not a problem of logical contradictions.

Comment: To be more specific: we do not observe them for cats. We do observe them for atoms, molecules, subatomic particles, etc...

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro well that's good , could you give me an example of superposition for atomic molecule i mean if we talking about spining of electrons it possible to spin up and spin down when we say electron is in superposition of spining up and down a|up>+b|down >can we observe or is detect this superposition or it's just a mathmatical structure to descripe the electron state before we making messurments

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro:  Your walking from one room to another affect's the Moon's orbit in classical physics.  The effect is too small to measure.  see [here](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21829184-700-earths-tides-are-shoving-the-moon-away-faster).

Comment: @John Doe: *Your walking from one room to another affect's the Moon's orbit in classical physics. The effect is too small to measure.* -- Of course it affect's the Moon's orbit. The point I was making is that NOT taking into account quantum mechanics in (most) classical physical settings, while technically not correct according to our best current understanding, is like NOT taking into account things like my walking from one room to another (or fleas jumping around on a dog's back) when calculating aspects of the Moon's orbit (also technically not correct according to our best current ...).

Answer (score 4):

Schrodinger's paradox is resolved by the fact that the cat exists in a superposition of states which contradicts determinism. We cannot determine whether or not the cat is alive until we observe the cat. This is not the same as a mathematical inconsistency which would allow us to prove that the cat is alive and to prove that the cat is dead.

You asked "Can any experiment contradict the laws of mathematical logic?". The answer is no. What can be determined by an experiment is whether or not a mathematical model is a valid description of a physical phenomenon.

Suppose we lived in a universe where we could prove, experimentally, that straight lines don't exist. Every theorem of Euclidean geometry would still be true. What may no longer be true is that Euclidean geometry is a good model for physical space.

Comment: +1 Good answer. And consider Hilary Putnam's [Is Logic Empirical? (1968)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_Logic_Empirical%3F): maybe also logic is "empirically determined" and our progress in the understanding of reality (in a broad sense) will need the adoption of a non-classical logic (exactly as the case of non-euclidean geometries).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Regarding Putnam's article, I suppose I should mention some writings by John Stuart Mill and Augustus De Morgan from the middle 1800s, which I discuss in my answer to [How do I convince someone that $1+1=2$ may not necessarily be true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246724/13130). (You've probably seen this before, as I've cited it often in Stack Exchange comments, but perhaps others here who would be interested haven't seen it.)

Comment: @John Douma I didn't understand the meaning of last sentense well  (suppose we lived in a universe ... )Is mean that logic can't applied in quantum physcis or you mean  if the result of the expermints oppose the mathmatical description then we should find other mathmatical models .

Comment: @MahmoudMrowi That is correct. In fact, some models only do well at certain scales like classical. relativity or classical gravitational theory. There was a mathematician named [George Box](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_E._P._Box) who once said "all models are wrong but some are useful".

Comment: @John Douma just to be sure ,we can say that the problem is not in logic, but in the interpretation of the mathematical model or the mathematical model of phenomena .Right like that?

Comment: @MahmoudMrowi I am not sure what you are asking. If you are trying to make sense of quantum mechanics you may waste this life doing so. Although we use mathematical models to describe many physical phenomena, mathematical truths are independent of physical reality.

Comment: @JohnDouma ok that's fine

Answer (score 2):

It is incorrect to assert that Schrödinger's cat or some subatomic particle is in a state $|\phi\rangle$of being $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ at the same time. Every such cat or particle is in a state that is a linear combination of two distinct vectors: $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. To say the cat is both fully dead *and* fully alive is to assert the following two statements:

$1.$ $|\phi\rangle = 1|0\rangle + 0|1\rangle = |0\rangle + |0\rangle = |0\rangle$

$2.$ $|\phi\rangle = 0|0\rangle + 1|1\rangle = |0\rangle + |1\rangle = |1\rangle$

which would lead to the contradiction $|0\rangle = |1\rangle$ by substitution. Hence, at least one of the above statements is false.

When the cat is in a state of superposition, its state is represented as follows

$ |\phi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$

such that $\alpha \neq 0, \beta \neq 0$ and $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$. According to the math, the best description of the cat's state is that the cat is *not* both fully dead and fully alive but *partially dead and partially alive*, and the extent to which it is either one depends on the corresponding amplitude $\alpha$ or $\beta$. In other words, the state of the cat is some combination of dead and alive. Now, this does not imply the cat is in the process of dieing or recovering. Whatever it means, it's definitely unfamiliar because the cat partially occupies two states we normally consider mutually exclusive. To make the weirdness more apparent, imagine partially eating a hamburger in America while talking to your mom while also partially sipping soup in China while watching a movie... and *you're doing all of this at the same time*. How can this be?

I don't think anyone truly understands what the math is pointing at. If you're familiar with Plato's allegory of the cave, the math is a shadow on the wall. It happens to be a good description of whatever is actually there (i.e. a model of reality), and it's even good at making predictions, but the math is not the substance. The true forms casting the shadows are out of sight.