# How are the elementary arithmetics defined?

Tags: real-analysis, arithmetic, real-numbers, natural-numbers, foundations

In the book Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, I read that "a < b" is defined this way: if b - a is positive, then a < b or b > a. Then some questions arose to me: we know that "minus" is a reverse operation of "plus" since a - b = a + (-b), but how is the elementary arithmetic "a + b" is defined, and how about "a * b"? Will there be any differences between the definitions with regard to the real number system, rational number system, and natural number system?

Comment: The [Peano axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) can be used to define the natural numbers, as well as $+$ and $*$ for the natural numbers.

Comment: [See my answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587948/how-to-prove-22-4-using-axioms-of-real-number-system/)

Comment: If $b-a \gt 0$, then $b \gt a$. You know $b \not \gt a$

Answer (score 12):

<sup>"God gave us the integers.

All else is the work of man."

Leopold Kronecker</sup>

A sketch of the ideas:

Addition and multiplication for  $a, b \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ can be defined by using Cauchy sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$.
$$
\begin{array}[llllll]\\
a+b&=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n+b_n), & a=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n, & a_n \in \mathbb{Q} & n \in \mathbb{N}\\
a \cdot b&=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n \cdot b_n), & b=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n, & b_n \in \mathbb{Q} \\ \tag{1}
\end{array}
$$

This works because the limes of the sum is independent of the sequences selected. So addition in $\mathbb{R}$
can be reduced to addition in $\mathbb{Q}$.

But addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Q} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$ can be reduced to addition in $\mathbb{Z}$
$$
\begin{array}[llllll]\\
a+b&=\frac{a_1b_2+b_1a_2}{a_2b_2}, & a=\frac{a_1}{a_2}, & a_n \in \mathbb{Z} & n \in \{1,2\} \\
a \cdot b&=\frac{a_1 \cdot b_1}{a_2 \cdot b_2}, & b=\frac{b_1}{b_2}, & b_n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{array} \\ \tag{2}
$$

And addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$ can be reduced to multiplication and addition in $\mathbb{N}$.
$$
\begin{array}[llllll]\\
a+b&=(a_1+b_1)-(a_2+b_2), & a=a_1-a_2, & a_n \in \mathbb{N} & n \in \{1,2\} \\
a \cdot b&=(a_1  b_1 + a_2  b_2) - (a_1  b_2 + a_2 b_1), & b=b_1-b_2, & b_n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{array} \\ \tag{3}
$$

All these definitions are independent of  the selected $a_n$ and $b_n$ as far as they meet the required specifications in regard of $a$ and $b$.

Multiplication in $\mathbb{N}$ can be reduced to addition in $\mathbb{N}$
$$
\begin{array}[llllll]\\
1 \cdot b&=b, &  a, b \in \mathbb{N} &  \\ 
a  \cdot b&=(a-1)b +b &  \\ 
\end{array} \\ \tag{4}
$$

Addition in $\mathbb{N}$ can be reduced to counting ($\text{successor}(n)$ of a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the number following $n$):

$$
\begin{array}[llllll]\\0+b&=b &  a, b \in \mathbb{N} & \\
a+b&=\text{successor}((a-1)+b)
\end{array} \\ \tag{5}
$$

Comment: Nice answer, really reduced it to the essence of the question