# How to prove that if $a,b$ are positive reals then also $ab$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, axioms

It might be a silly question but I can't find how to prove this.

I assume this has a proof per axiomatic system but I am looking for proof which is most standard, using the most common axiomatic system.

e.g. when proving $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ is a group with multiplication, we usually just state it is closed without prooving.

To be more specific, how to prove it using ZFC?

Comment: One of the most common axiomatic systems for the real line uses this as an axiom. If it's not "the most common" (whatever that means), it'd probably be top two (in the context of introductory real analysis). You really should specify the axiom system that you're interested in.

Comment: For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach

Comment: See the top of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1009195/11206)  of [How are the elementary arithmetics defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003994/11206) that reduces the case of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are the elementary arithmetics defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003994/how-are-the-elementary-arithmetics-defined)

Comment: Many books on it; see e.g. Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis (Springer, 2011)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Real_Numbers_and_Real_Analysis/r0qcU9U2_I4C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the reals are defined as the metric completion of $\mathbb Q$, using Cauchy sequences. They inherit an ordering from $\mathbb Q$ and it suffices to prove that $\mathbb Q_+ \cdot \mathbb Q_+ \subset \mathbb Q_+$.

Now $\mathbb Q$ is defined as the fraction field of $\mathbb Z$. An explicit construction is as pairs $(a, b) \in \mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z - \{0\})$ modulo the equivalence relation of being proportional by a nonzero integer. The multiplication is entrywise, and it is not hard to define $\mathbb Q_+$ once you have defined $\mathbb Z_+$, and to reduce the question to proving that $\mathbb Z_+ \cdot \mathbb Z_+ \subset \mathbb Z_+$.

Now $\mathbb Z$ is constructed out of $\mathbb N$ and (practically by definition) $\mathbb Z _+ = \mathbb N$, and $\mathbb Z_+ \cdot \mathbb Z_+ \subset \mathbb Z_+$ is then true because the multiplication on $\mathbb Z_+$ is the same as the one on $\mathbb N$.