# Are there different types of infinity?

Tags: infinity

Today in class my professor mentioned that there are different types of infinity. This confused me at first because I always thought infinity is just infinity. What are the different types of infinity?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1/different-kinds-of-infinities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor was talking about the distinction between [countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) & [uncountable sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set), established by [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). See also [Aleph number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number), [Beth number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number), [equinumerosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity), & [Cantor's contributions to set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor#Set_theory).

Comment: There's not only different *sizes* of infinity, but indeed also different *kinds* of infinity. For example, the usage of the symbol $\infty$ in limits, series, one-point-compactifications, ... is not really about cardinalities of sets.