# How many integers between $1$ and $10^n$ contain $14$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How can we derive a formula to calculate the number of integers between $1$ and $10^n$ that contain the number $14$ (as a string)?

For example, there are $20$ integers from $1$ to $1000$ that contain at least one $14$:

> "14","114","140","141","142","143","144","145","146","147","148","149","214","314","414","514","614","714","814","914"

Comment: Contain 14 as a factor, or a pair of digits, or...?

Comment: What is 14"? If it is the end of a quotation mark, then is it a homework question? This is an unclear question with no context or effort displayed; see also Zach's comment above.

Comment: look: http://codebin.org/view/6b4922a3

Comment: @aon Comments are not how you clarify your question. The way to clarify your question is to edit your question. Please make this question clear.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I've updated the question.

Comment: Possible numbers between 1 and 1000 that contain the digit sequence 14 look like 14XX, X14X, and XX14. Now consider the overlaps.

Comment: @aon: I am glad to see that my value for $n=4$ matches your count :-)

Answer (score 12):

There are $\binom{n-k}{k}$ arrangements of $k$ "$14$"s and $10^{n-2k}$ other digits.

Thus, inclusion-exclusion says there are
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n-k}{k}10^{n-2k}\tag{1}
$$
numbers from $1$ to $10^n$ which contain "$14$".

Here are some of the first few values.
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
n&\text{count}\\
\hline
2&1\\
3&20\\
4&299\\
5&3970\\
6&49401\\
7&590040
\end{array}\tag{2}
$$

---

**Generating Function**

Multiply $(1)$ by $x^n$ and sum:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n-k}{n-2k}10^{n-2k}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-k-1}\binom{-k-1}{n-2k}10^{n-2k}x^{n-2k}x^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{2k}}{(1-10x)^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac1{10x-1}\frac{\frac{x^2}{10x-1}}{1-\frac{x^2}{10x-1}}\\
&=\frac{x^2}{1-20x+101x^2-10x^3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
which has the Taylor series $x^2+20x^3+299x^4+3970x^5+49401x^6+590040x^7+\dots$

---

**Closed Form**

The denominator in $(3)$ says that $c_n$ satisfies
$$
c_n=20c_{n-1}-101c_{n-2}+10c_{n-3}\tag{4}
$$
The characteristic polynomial for $(4)$ is
$$
x^3-20x^2+101x-10\tag{5}
$$
whose roots are
$$
\left\{10,5+\sqrt{24},5-\sqrt{24}\right\}\tag{6}
$$
We can solve $(4)$ in the standard manner for such recurrences to get
$$
c_n=10^n-\frac{(5+\sqrt{24})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{24}}+\frac{(5-\sqrt{24})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{24}}\tag{7}
$$

Comment: how to calculate it? in order to obtain the end result? I mean, the formula mean.

Comment: @aon: there are three ways mentioned above to calculate the number of strings containing "$14$". The summation in $(1)$, the recursion in $(4)$, and the closed form in $(7)$. I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you are asking how to compute $(7)$, then we just need to know that the solutions to the recurrence $(4)$ are of the form $c_n=x10^n+y(5+\sqrt{24})^n+z(5-\sqrt{24})^n$. Just use the known values of $c_n$ for three different $n$ to compute $x,y,z$ using linear algebra.

Comment: Can you give an example of calculating how many integers between 1 and 10,000 containing 14?

Comment: That is $n=4$. In the sum that is
$$
\binom{4-1}{1}10^{4-2\cdot1}-\binom{4-2}{2}10^{4-2\cdot2}=300-1=299
$$
In the closed form, that is
$$
\begin{align}
10^4-\frac{(5+\sqrt{24})^5}{2\sqrt{24}}+\frac{(5-\sqrt{24})^5}{2\sqrt{24}} &=10000-\left(\frac{9701}{2} +\frac{47525}{2\sqrt{24}}\right)+\left(-\frac{9701}{2} +\frac{47525}{2\sqrt{24}}\right)\\&=10000-9701\\&=299
\end{align}
$$
We can also use $10000-9701.00000107377+0.00000107377=299$

Comment: I tried it for n = 5, but the results are not suitable, what possible way I wrong?

((5-1 x 1) x 10^5-(2x1)) - ((5-2 x 2) x 10^5-(2x2))
4 x 1000 - 6 x 10
3940

Comment: @aon: $$\binom{5-1}{1}10^{5-2\cdot1}-\binom{5-2}{2}10^{5-2\cdot2}=4000-30=3970$$ or $100000-96030.0000001085+0.0000001085=3970$.

Comment: 30 the results of the calculation value how?

Comment: @aon: $\binom32=3$ and $10^1=10$.

Comment: 3 from where? 3=3 or 3/2=3, or? sorry I need a detailed explanation.

Comment: @aon: Please read about [Binomial Coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). They are very important in [Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

Comment: for n=1.000.000, result is 49.400.
50.000 - 600 = 49.400. what is wrong?

Comment: @aon: $n=6$: $$\binom{6-1}{1}10^{6-2\cdot1}-\binom{6-2}{2}10^{6-2\cdot2}+\binom{6-3}{3}10^{6-2\cdot3}=50000-600+1=49401$$

Comment: why there is value to sum? whereas at n = 4 and n = 5, there is no such addition.

Comment: @aon: Note the upper limit of summation in $(1)$.

Comment: I still do not understand. sorry.

Comment: @aon: the sum for $n=4$ and $n=5$ is from $k=1$ to $k=2$ whereas the sum for $n=6$ and $n=7$ is from $k=1$ to $k=3$. This is the $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$ in the upper limit of the summation in $(1)$.

Comment: so, n = 8 and n = 9, k = 1 to k = 4. for n = 10 and n = 11, k = 1 to k = 5. is that so?

Comment: @aon: yes, do you know about the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)?

Comment: do not know much, because I am not proficient in math :)
so what?

Comment: @aon: So what? So you should start learning basic mathematics instead of trying to solve a problem that is meaningless if you don't even understand basic mathematics. robjohn was already extremely patient with you, but it is not productive unless you put in the effort to learn.

Answer (score 7):

If the number if length-$n$ numbers containing $14$ is $f(n)$; call these numbers "good", then we have the recurrence $$f(n)=10 f(n-1)-f(n-2)+10^{n-2}$$ for $n \geq 3$: the argument is that we can construct length-$n$ good numbers from length-$(n-1)$ good numbers by appending any digit, or by appending $14$ to any length-$(n-2)$ number; this double-counts numbers with multiple $14$s ending in $14$, so we subtract $f(n-2)$ to account for this.

This gives the sequence $$0, 1, 20, 299, 3970, 49401, 590040, 6850999, 77919950, 872348501, \ldots.$$

Comment: how to calculate it? in order to obtain the end result? I mean, the formula mean.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant on [Rebecca Stone's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924399/how-many-integers-between-1-and-10n-contain-14/924843#924843).  Let $G(n)$ count the number of "good" length-$n$ strings that contain a $14$, and let $B(n)$ count the number of "bad" strings that don't.  Clearly

$$G(n)+B(n)=10^n$$

You can create a bad string of length $n$ by appending any digit you want to a bad string of length $n-1$, unless the shorter string ends in a $1$, in which case you can't append a $4$.  The number of such strings (ending in a $1$) is $B(n-2)$.  Thus

$$B(n)=10B(n-1)-B(n-2)$$

with starting values $B(1)=10$ and $B(2)=99$.  This gives the the "bad" sequence

$$10, 99, 980, 9701, 96030, 950599, 9409960, 93149001,\ldots$$

which is [A004189](http://oeis.org/A004189) in the OEIS, where it's noted that

$$B(n)={(5+\sqrt{24})^{n+1}-(5-\sqrt{24})^{n+1}\over2\sqrt{24}}$$

Thus

$$G(n)=10^n-{(5+\sqrt{24})^{n+1}\over2\sqrt{24}}+{(5-\sqrt{24})^{n+1}\over2\sqrt{24}}$$

as [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924399/how-many-integers-between-1-and-10n-contain-14/924835#924835) found.

Comment: It is interesting that the bad strings give a nice recursion. +1

Answer (score 0):

Might not be a solution you want, but this little code snippet in Javascript does your work.
This returns 20 as an output for 1000. 
299 for 10000.

```
 var count = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
 if (i.toString().search("14") != -1) {
     count++;
 }
 }
 alert(count);
```